# How are ions formed?

Tags: atoms, atomic-structure

I know that $\ce{H2O}$ is neutral.
So how does adding one more hydrogen atom to it make it positive ion ($\ce{H3O+}$)?

Comment: Hi Hark, welcome to Chem.SE! Where did you read that addition of an hydrogen **atom** forms a hydronium ion? In fact, it doesn't. Hydronium ions are formed by addition of a proton to a water molecule.

Comment: So all ions are formed this way?

Comment: Ions are always charged. You cannot hope to form them by combining one atom with another atom.

Comment: How is sulphate ion formed?

Comment: Deprotonation of sulphuric acid. Twice.

Comment: Is it possible to make neutral SO4? How?

Comment: A "neutral ion" does not exist. Neutral gases of a similar formula - SO3 and SO2 - do exist, though they are not ions.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw in the question is exactly what [Gaurang Tandon said](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91264/#comment167288_91264): $\ce{H3O^+}$ is formed by a water molecule and a **proton** ($\ce{H^+}$), not a hydrogen atom.

Compare the **number of electrons** in both sides of the following two equations:

$$\ce{H2O + H^+ -> H3O^+}$$

$$\ce{H2O + H^. -> H3O^+}$$

The last equation is wrong: there's an extra electron in the left hand side.